# Make VS Code editor Ctrl+Tab cycle tabs in the same order as they're displayed on screen?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, opensuse

When I go thru open tabs in VS Code by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcut, the next tab to display is not always the next tab over to the right of currently displayed. *(I am taking wrap-around into account; this also happens when the current tab isn't rightmost)* This is a problem for me from an aesthetic/UX point of view because tab changing feels out of sync with the gui, & it slows me down.

I'd be happy with a solution that either makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> follow the order displayed onscreen or makes the displayed order follow whatever order <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is using. Thanks if you have any info

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches tabs in the order of last use. *(The tabs are switched to in reverse chronological order)*

According to the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface), by default, the method to switch tabs linearly is as follows:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>: Go left an Editor (Command: `workbench.action.previousEditor`)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>: Go right an Editor (Command: `workbench.action.nextEditor`)

Of course, these are remapable to your liking, but these are the defaults.

Comment: @NathanSmith Does this work for you? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it does. I went into keymappings & adjusted the linear tab switching commands ( 'open next|previous editor' ) swapping them for the history based commands tied to ctrl+tab by default

Comment: It may be worth adding the names for these commands are `workbench.action.previousEditor` `workbench.action.nextEditor` (for when you're looking to change them)

Comment: @csilk Yes! I'm not sure why they weren't there in the first place.

Comment: For those looking to revert back to default: `Ctrl + Tab` was mapped to `workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`, `Ctrl + Shift + Tab` to `workbench.action.quickOpenLeastRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`

Answer (score 18):

In %AppData%\Code\User\keybindings.json add this:

```
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+tab", 
    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor" 
},
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+shift+tab", 
    "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor" 
},
```

Comment: this can be edited in the GUI now. Click settings -> Keyboard shortcuts